# How to pass a user-defined Data Type parameter to SSRS report query?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have the following User-defined Data Type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[StringList] AS TABLE(
    [String] [varchar](8000) NULL
)
```

How to pass a user-defined Data Type parameter to **SSRS** report query?

Comment: I doubt that there an easy way of doing this

Comment: @Simonare, you're right! I gave up and thought of another solution. Thanxs!